# Why can I remove file without user permission?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, console

I made small test to check how permissions work:

```
test@comp ~/Documents $ touch test1
test@comp ~/Documents $ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 test test     0 Jul 24 22:14 test1
test@comp ~/Documents $ chmod 044 test1 
test@comp ~/Documents $ ls -l
----r--r-- 1 test test 0 Jul 24 22:14 test1
test@comp ~/Documents $ cat test1
cat: test1: Permission denied
test@comp ~/Documents $ rm test1
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘test1’? y
test@comp ~/Documents $ ls -l
total 0
```

My question is, why when I have no permission on user I can't read file but I can remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove the file one needs a *write* permission on the *directory* that contains this file.

For more information: http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php